# Get "Ping Time" with Twisted Server

Tags: python, twisted, ping

I got a Twisted Game server and I want to make a "ping" command server-side. (The client sends commands to server and the server do thnigs, and answer).

But I can't thing any way to get "Ping Time" of a connection between the server and the client. Is there a way to get it, for example with

```
self.transport
```

or other. But I can't find.
Any ideas please?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"ping time" is not an inherent property of a connection, but rather, the amount of time it takes for the client to send a do-nothing request to the server and have the server send an answer.

If you were using, for example, [AMP](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.5.0/api/twisted.protocols.amp.AMP.html), you could do something like this:

```
def pingTime(self):
    then = reactor.seconds()
    def pung(ignored):
        now = reactor.seconds()
        return now - then
    return self.callRemote(Ping).addCallback(pung)
```

Comment: thanks, but I got something like "0.0200209617615" ... probably "* 1000"

Comment: The value is a number of seconds, so if you did `* 1000` you'd get a number of milliseconds.